# Spring 4: MethodInvokingFactoryBean on a FactoryBean<> instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a FreeMarker configuration in Spring 4 using `org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean`, and then customising the resulting `freemarker.template.Configuration` (to change the arithmetic engine).

I'm using the following XML config (simplified):

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfiguration" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
  <property name="templateLoaderPaths">...</property>
   ...
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="freemarkerConfiguration" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setArithmeticEngine" />
    <property name="arguments" value="#{T(freemarker.core.ArithmeticEngine).CONSERVATIVE_ENGINE}" />
</bean>
```

It works, but I get a lot of warnings during the application startup:

```
2015-02-27 13:53:03,321 [localhost-startStop-1] [:] WARN  support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/freemarker.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'freemarkerConfiguration' while setting bean property 'targetObject'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'freemarkerConfiguration': FactoryBean which is currently in creation returned null from getObject
```

My understanding is that it happens because the `FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean` implements the [`FactoryBean<>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) interface. As such, this `FactoryBean` is "prepared" first, and then `FactoryBean.getObject()` is called whenever the actual bean it creates (`freemarker.template.Configuration`) needs to be accessed.

It seems the `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` gets invoked while the underlying bean is still being "prepared" by `FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean`, resulting in `FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean.getObject()` returning `null` and the method invocation failing.

I suspect I'm getting a lot of warnings because Spring repeatedly tries to invoke the method and fails. At some point the bean produced by the factory is ready, and the method invocation works.

So:

- Is my analysis correct?
- Why is that happenning? I would think the dependency injection system should detect the dependency between the `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` and the `freemarkerConfiguration`, and invoke the method *after* the factory bean is ready. I tried to add `depends-on="freemarkerConfiguration"` on the `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` but it didn't help.
- Is there a way to achieve what I want in XML (I can't switch to Java `@Configuration` right now). Basically I need a way to call `freemarker.core.Configurable.setArithmeticEngine()` from XML.

Thanks.

Comment: I try to reproduce your issue with a simple project, but there aren't warning of any type, 
I've used: spring version: 4.1.1, freemarker: 2.3.20

The only log info is: org.springframework.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader.<init> SpringTemplateLoader for FreeMarker: using resource loader [WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [...]; root of context hierarchy] and template loader path [/WEB-INF/freemarker/]

Don't know if it's useful for you but If you need all the configuration file I can post it in an answer.(pom.xml, spring.xml, web.xml ...)

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I've another suggestion: try to configure also: <prop key="template_exception_handler" >foo.bar.MyTemplateExceptionHandler</prop>Your exception handler must have an INSTANCE field populated from context, please see example:public class MyTemplateExceptionHandler implements TemplateExceptionHandler {    static ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");    public static MyTemplateExceptionHandler INSTANCE = context.getBean(MyTemplateExceptionHandler.class);[...]} this work for object builder expressions after version 2.3.21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading some spec I find this, hope is useful for you:

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfiguration" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/freemarker/"/>
    <property name="freemarkerSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="arithmetic_engine">conservative</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

ref: [Freemarker Docs](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/core/Configurable.html#setSetting-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The thing is that I used arithmetic engine to make the problem simpler to describe :) but what I actually need is to inject a custom template exception handler that's a Spring bean. I guess I should have mentioned that in the question! I can't use this approach here because while FreeMarker can construct objects for those settings, it cannot take a reference to a Spring bean. However that's solves my original question so I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A `FactoryBean` is supposed to create a bean, not to call a method on a bean! Also the method invoking version will try to create a bean by calling the configured method of the object passed to create a new bean.

What you should look on instead, is the `freemarkerSettings` property of the `FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean` and set properties including the arithmetic engine:

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfiguration" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
  <property name="templateLoaderPaths">...</property>
  <property name="freemarkerSettings">
    <map>
      <entry key="#{T(freemarker.core.Configurable).ARITHMETIC_ENGINE_KEY}"
        value="#{T(freemarker.core.ArithmeticEngine).CONSERVATIVE_ENGINE}"/>
    </map>
  </property>
   ...
</bean>
```

Comment: I understand a `FactoryBean` is meant to create a bean, but I thought `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` was the recommended way to call arbitrary methods on beans. It can create a bean, yes, but it also supports calling methods that don't return value. Is there a better way to call arbitrary methods (which are not properties) on beans, or you  just not supposed to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean about the `configuration` property of `FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean`. This bean has no such property as far as I can tell from the Javadoc? It supports setting some properties (`templateLoaderPath`, `freemarkerSettings`, etc.) but no the one I need (arithmetic engine).

Comment: sorry, din't meant configuration, use freemarkerSettings instead

Comment: "I thought MethodInvokingFactoryBean was the recommended way to call arbitrary methods on beans" NO, it is also to create a bean BY invoking a method!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately still no dice. I get a `NullPointerException` in the FreeMarker code when it tries to read the value for the `ARITHMETIC_ENGINE_KEY`. In any case I'm not sure that would have worked because `freemarkerSettings` is actually a `java.util.Properties` (not a `Map`) and looking at the code of `freemarker.core.Configurable.setSettings()` it clearly expect `String` values. My problem is that I need to pass objects (the arithmetic engine, but I also have a custom template exception handler I need to configure).